# Master-detail view using textBoxes and ADO

Tags: c#, binding, ado.net

The problem I'm fighting with is binding data from MySql to the textBoxes in C#.
Using dataGridView it looks like that:

```
DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString , connection);
DataAdapter.Fill(dataSet1,"show");
DataAdapterDetail.Fill(dataSet1, "detail");                   
DataRelation Relation = new DataRelation("FK_Zadanie_Pracownik", 
dataSet1.Tables["show"].Columns["ID"],
dataSet1.Tables["detail"].Columns["ID"]);                
dataSet1.Relations.Add(Relation);
bindingSource1.DataSource = dataSet1;
bindingSource1.DataMember = "show";
bindingSource2.DataSource = bindingSource1;
bindingSource2.DataMember = "FK_Zadanie_Pracownik";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

And my question is how to do the same but using combobox with the first bindingSource, and the textbox with the second.

EDIT:

I was trying to do something like that, using DataRelations:

```
        DataRelation ZameldowaniaMieszkancy = new DataRelation("ZamMiesz", dsZameldowania.Tables["Zameldowania"].Columns["id_mieszkanca"], dsZameldowania.Tables["Mieszkancy"].Columns["id"], false); 
        bsOsoba = new BindingSource();
        bsOsoba.DataSource = dsZameldowania;
        bsOsoba.DataMember = "Zameldowania";

        design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.DataSource = bsOsoba;
        design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.ValueMember = "ZamMiesz.nazwiskoImie";
        design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.DisplayMember = "ZamMiesz.nazwiskoImie";
```

But it's showing me only the first result from the DB (only one row-to-row relation) and not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind your dataset with ComboBox like this

```
mycombo.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["show"];
```

After that you have to set DisplayMember and ValueMember of the ComboBox

```
mycombo.DisplayMember = "ColumnNameToDisplay";
mycombo.ValueMember = "ColumnNameForID";
```

For TextBox value you have to define specified column and row of the datatable
Like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = dataSet1.Tables["show"].Rows[RowIndex]["Column Name"].ToString();
```

If dropdown and textbox is in Grid than you have to perform the same thing in RowDataBoundEvent of Grid.

Comment: @peter, I was trying to do something like: `DataRelation ZameldowaniaMieszkancy = new DataRelation("ZamMiesz", dsZameldowania.Tables["Zameldowania"].Columns["id_mieszkanca"], dsZameldowania.Tables["Mieszkancy"].Columns["id"], false); bsOsoba = new BindingSource();
bsOsoba.DataSource = dsZameldowania;
bsOsoba.DataMember = "Zameldowania";
design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.DataSource = bsOsoba;
design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.ValueMember = "ZamMiesz.nazwiskoImie";
design.comboBoxFiltrNazwisko.DisplayMember = "ZamMiesz.nazwiskoImie";` but it's showing me only the first result from db, and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to take a look at this little tutorial over [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)